# Load Data from API into App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I have data returned from API call, which is an array. I want to create a list in App Maker to display the items in the array. I have already put my API calling in sever script. How can I load the data into list widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform response from your API into [Calculated Model](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/calculated)'s records and then load and bind them on UI:

```js
// Server script
function getCaluculatedModelRecords() {
  var apiObjects = getMyMagicObjectsFromApi();

  return apiObjects.map(function(apiObj) {
    var record = app.models.MyCalculatedModel.newRecord();

    record.Field1 = apiObj.field1;
    record.Field2 = apiObj.field2;
    record.Field3 = apiObj.field3;
    ...

    return record;
  });
}
```

Maybe this sample will be somehow helpful as well: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/calculated-model/